# distribution certificate validity for ios

Tags: ios

how to create distribution certificate with the validity morethan 10 years ?
or
does the B2B app installed using distribution certificate in device, will it work after expiration of certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You can not create certificates with validity of 10 years. Certificates are signing the application. So, if you have valid provisional profile installed on device, you can use the application even if certificates are expired.